# Every document read in a transaction must also be written : Firestore Transaction Exception in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore Transactions is giving me the following error :

> Caused by: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: Every document read in a transaction must also be written.

Here's the piece of code:

```
   db.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void apply(Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {


            DocumentReference docRef2 = db.collection("ABC").document(mMatchedUserId);

            DocumentReference ref3 = db.collection("XYZ").document(mCurrentUserId);
            DocumentReference ref4 = db.collection("XYZ").document(mMatchedUserId);


            DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot2 = transaction.get(docRef2);

            if(documentSnapshot2.exists())
            {
                transaction.delete(docRef2);
                transaction.set(ref3, myMap1);
                transaction.set(ref4,myMap2);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Transaction success!");
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Transaction failure.", e);
        }
    });
```

If I remove this if condition :`if(documentSnapshot1.exists() && documentSnapshot2.exists())` then the transaction completes successfully and there is no error.

But the major point of setting up this transaction was the if condition. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code lies in the fact that inside your transaction you are reading two documents:

```
DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot1 = transaction.get(docRef1);
DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot2 = transaction.get(docRef2);
```

But you never write them back. As I see in your code, you only need them to a delete operation so in such case, read them before the transaction rather than inside the transaction and your problem will be solved.

Comment: I have edited the question to remove transaction.get(docRef1) as I don't need it.

I delete docRef2 inside the if condition. (delete() is a write operation.

Comment: I am reading it inside the transaction to solve this problem.
Let's say document C is in the collection.
Client A and B, both see C near simultaneously and initiate a delete operation ( and 2 more related operations) together.
I want either A and B to do it, but not both of them together. 
So I have to check it within the transaction if it exists and only then delete it.

Comment: I understand but you should write that data back. There is no need to use a transaction in order to delete some data, you can simply use `delete()` directly on the reference. So try to isolate the code that doesn't belong to a transaction. Remember that a transaction absolutely requires a round trip communications with server in order to ensure that the code inside the transaction completes successfully. So read data, check if it's what you need, write it back.

Comment: I will note that every document you write in a transaction should also have been read by the transaction (not outside of the transaction using a DoucmentReference). Otherwise, your documents could end up in an inconsistent state if one of them changes before the write takes place.